# TabHost.setCurrentTab() method is not working

Tags: android, android-tabhost

> I am using TabHost and I have to change the default Tabselected
>   according to the users selected option in previous class but it is not working.

Here is my code.

```
 public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
        String getselectevalue ="0";

         private static final String TAB_1_TAG = "tab_1";
         private static final String TAB_2_TAG = "tab_2";
         private static final String TAB_3_TAG = "tab_3";
         private static final String TAB_4_TAG = "tab_4";
         private static final String TAB_5_TAG = "tab_5";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tabs);

            InitView();
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(this);
            // mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
            // R.id.menu_settings);

            try{
            getselectevalue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedVlaue");
            }catch(Exception e){

            }

            Log.d("got the value here", getselectevalue);


        }

         private void InitView() {
              mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);


                    mTabHost.addTab(setIndicator(FirstActivity.this,mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG),
                            R.drawable.tab_indicator_gen,"Post",R.drawable.post_unselected),Fragment1.class,null);
                    mTabHost.addTab(setIndicator(FirstActivity.this,mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG),
                              R.drawable.tab_indicator_gen,"Profile",R.drawable.profile_unselect),Fragment2.class,null);
                    mTabHost.addTab(setIndicator(FirstActivity.this,mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3_TAG),
                              R.drawable.tab_indicator_gen,"Chat",R.drawable.chat_unselected),Fragment3.class,null);
                    mTabHost.addTab(setIndicator(FirstActivity.this,mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_4_TAG),
                              R.drawable.tab_indicator_gen,"Event",R.drawable.event_unselcted),Fragment3.class,null);
                    mTabHost.addTab(setIndicator(FirstActivity.this,mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_5_TAG),
                              R.drawable.tab_indicator_gen,"Fragment",R.drawable.shop_unselected),Fragment3.class,null);


                       if(getselectevalue.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

                        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

                        }else{

                            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                        }
               }



             private TabSpec setIndicator(Context ctx, TabSpec spec,
               int resid, String string, int genresIcon) {
                  View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.tab_item, null);
                  v.setBackgroundResource(resid);
                  TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_tabtxt);
                  ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_tabtxt);

                  tv.setText(string);
                  img.setBackgroundResource(genresIcon);
                  return spec.setIndicator(v);
             }
```

> Please have a look and let me know what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: call `InitView();` after `catch` block

Comment: thnks, It worked.. :)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya but everytime it is opening only 0 position tab

Comment: because you initialize `String getselectevalue ="0";`

Comment: you can try with `if(getselectevalue.matches("0")`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya same condition. everytime it called tab at 0 position.

Comment: Let me sure `Log.d` returns properly ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes... it is returning the proper selected value/

Comment: Okay .Set `Log.d` before `if(getselectevalue.equalsIgnoreCase` .Let me feedback

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya both time it is giving the same value.03-08 15:26:11.964: D/got the value here(20230): 3
03-08 15:26:11.991: D/got the value here again(20230): 3

Comment: what is `3` .  Set This InitView section `Log.d("Before", getselectevalue);` & this oncreate section `Log.d("Oncreate", getselectevalue);`

Comment: remove `=0` just from `String getselectevalue ="0";`

Comment: Did you fix this yet ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , In my previous activity, there are 5 options to select. if user select any option from that, it should move to SecondTab in current activity and if he escape the selection, it should be at firstTab(0 position).

Comment: Problem for `getselectevalue` .I assume my logic/answer true .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, But When I am getting the correct selected value, then how it is not working here. I dont understand.

Comment: Solve this problem yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes, I dont know wat was wrong with. Same code is working fine now.. :/

Comment: Move ahead . Happy coding .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks for your kind help.. :)

Comment: Glad to help . Enjoy Coding .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first Call `InitView();` method  after **`catch block`** .

```
 try 
    {
    getselectevalue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedVlaue");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
   InitView();
```